# Does any university accept bitcoin to take course fee?

Tags: education

Which universities of the World accept bitcoins to take their course fee? Can it be done by bitcoins? I need to know it as I am planning to take some courses for higher education from an reported University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

University of Cumbria, a British University, is the first Public University accepting bitcoin in the UK for two of its courses. “Certificate of Achievement in Sustainable Exchange”, will be taught at Cumbria’s London campus, and the “Postgraduate Certificate in Sustainable Leadership”, which will take place at the Lake District campus. http://www.independent.co.uk/student/news/cumbria-becomes-first-public-university-in-the-world-to-accept-bitcoin-in-tuition-fees-9074700.html

Other options globally include the University of Nicosia in Cyprus (http://www.unic.ac.cy/news-and-events/73/unic-to-be-the-first-university-in-the-world-to-accept-bitcoin/112831#.UuFCG9LnaUk) and there are unsubstantiated rumors that Novi Sad in Serbia takes them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cambria University take tution fees as Bitcoin the report states :

> London:  A university in the UK has become the first public varsity in the world to allow students to pay their tuition fees with the digital currency Bitcoin.
>
> Students at Cumbria University attending two courses examining the role of complementary currencies will be allowed to use the units.
>
> Last year the University of Nicosia, a private university in Cyprus, announced it would accept Bitcoin, but the University of Cumbria is the first public university to do so, and for courses that are already validated and accepting students.
>
> Cumbria's system for accepting payments, via the Bitpay system, is already operational, the university said in a statement.

The complete report can be read on the following URL

http://www.ndtv.com/article/world/british-university-to-accept-tuition-fees-in-bitcoin-474086